# Are there any functional programming languages designed for code-golfing?

Tags: tips, functional-programming, golfing-language

Are there any functional programming languages designed for code golfing? I know that golfscript and CJam fulfill the same category for stack based, but I couldn't find a functional code golfing language.

Comment: Define "functional programming languages".

Comment: Do you mean something like Haskell?

Comment: There's [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip) by Ypnypn and Leo and Zgarb are currently designing and implementing a Haskell-based golfing language called [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk).

Comment: If C qualifies as a functional language, I wrote [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has an answer on the meta site: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/what-programming-languages-have-been-created-by-ppcg-users

Comment: @mbomb007 Except that it's limited to languages created by PPCG users... (and contains neither Clip nor Husk but has several languages claiming they're functional although they aren't).

Comment: [Burlesque](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Burlesque) isn't entirely functional, but it does have one of the trademark features of functional programming languages, namely lazy lists.

Comment: Jelly is tacit, and tacit implies functional, doesn't it?

Comment: @MDXF I am assuming the definition of a functional language to be one that primarily uses the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm. Although C has functions, it is typically considered to be a [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) language.

Comment: @BetaDecay Shouldn't this be on the meta site, though? The question is at least similar to the one I linked, and fits more on meta, I'd think.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's not a question about PPCG so it definitely doesn't belong on meta. Whether it belongs on main is arguable, but since we allow other kinds of non-challenge questions about golfing in general (including golfing tips, questions about golfing language design and questions about challenge writing) I don't think this is a bad fit for main.

Comment: @mbomb007 No, this is effectively a tips question which are most definitely on topic on main

Comment: What are functional programming languages? [Pure BF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pure_BF) isn't a golfing language, but you could do the same thing to some other languages.

Comment: @MDXF [The C language is purely functional](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional)

Comment: Would Jelly count as functional?

Comment: @mbomb007 Having an answer on meta doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: @MartinEnder It's not just lists that are lazy, the language itself has lazy evaluation as for example noticeable when writing code like `1R@<-L[vv1`. Of course, this property is barely of any use in real code as it's mostly only useful for lists but the language itself is lazy. `1R@<-L[` ([eval](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=1R%40%3C-L%5Bvv1)) would inverse an infinite list and calculate it's length which would never terminate but `vv` pops an element from the stack so the result of that computation is never needed and thus it's never actually evaluated.

Answer (score 12):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk)

Husk is a pure functional golfing language created by me and [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo) and inspired by Haskell.
It combines a rigid type system, type inference and extensive overloading.
Functions are first class values and can be manipulated as easily as other data.
Development of Husk is ongoing and many features are still missing, but you can try it out at [TIO](https://tio.run/#husk).
We also have a [SE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53097/husk) for the language.

Answer (score 3):

### [cQuents](https://esolangs.org/wiki/cQuents)

cQuents is an inpure functional golfing language. It incorporates a lot of functional programming concepts, notably lazy evaluation and infinite lists, since it's specifically designed to do well in [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) related challenges.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth

Pyth is a functional language that transpiles to python